# Start-BitsTransfer doesn't work with winRM protocol

Tags: powershell, winrm, rundeck, microsoft-bits

Hy,

I try to launch Start-BitsTransfer command with a Rundeck Job.
I have the error : `The remote use of BITS is not supported.`

I launch some powershell commands with succes.

Thanks

Comment: [Known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/743030/make-it-easier-to-use-bits-with-powershell-remoting). It's [fixed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ee663885.aspx#manage_ps_remote_sessions) in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. On earlier machines, you'd have to concoct some nasty workaround where you kick off a local process.

Comment: I use a Windows Server 2012 environment. Know you if a KB exists ?

Comment: No, I don't. I'd be surprised, because this is not a bug but missing functionality, and there are only rarely KB articles for those unless the question is very common. I don't think this one is.

Answer (score 0):

I used wget command. 
But it works with a little item. When I try to download a big item (3Go) I have this error : `com.xebialabs.overthere.cifs.winrm.WinRmRuntimeIOException : Unexpected HTTP response ..`

I have create a new [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840196/impossible-to-take-a-wget-with-winrm-protocol)