# Impossible to take a wget with winrm protocol

Tags: winrm, rundeck

I am using Rundeck. I'm tring to use a wget with the WinRM protocol,
It works with a little item but when I try to download a big item (3Go) I have this error :

`com.xebialabs.overthere.cifs.winrm.WinRmRuntimeIOException : Unexpected HTTP response ..` HTTP error 500.

The problem is about a Winrm config ? Timeout configuration ?

Log trace :

`[overthere-winrm:...] failed: WinRM Error: Unexpected HTTP response on http: http://...:5985/wsman: (500)`

Comment: Can you paste the error log please?

Comment: Maybe the MaxEnvelopeSizekb property in wirm/config. Default is 150kbs, go to C:\Windows\System32 and change it with 'winrm set winrm/config @{MaxEnvelopeSizekb= "X"}' where X is maximum size you need. Remember is on Kbs.

Comment: I have set the MaxEnvelopeSizekb  property to 1039440

Comment: And it's working ? :)

Comment: No ... I also set the MaxTimeoutms property to 600000 and it's not working

Comment: Does the error message come up after the download started? are you running rundeck on a VM?